# Use frameset with other HTML elements in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, frames, frameset

I have a page in which I want to include frameset, as well as use other HTML elements (basically some hidden form fields). But where can I place those additional HTML elements in the code ?

```
<frameset cols="*" rows="40,*">             
<frame src="#" />             
<frame src="#"/>             
<noframes>                 
<body>                 
Please enable frames to view.
</body>             
</noframes>         
</frameset>
```

Comment: It makes no sense at all to have form fields in a frameset document (other then in the document for users who don't have frames capable browsers (telling people to turn frames on is not helpful BTW)). Why do you think you need this? And why is this tagged CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: Even though I know frameset is kind of outdated..the application I am working on is a legacy app and I do not have much control (or rather need a lot of approvals before making any such kind of changes)...That is the reason I am using frameset...

Comment: I mean "Why do you think you need form fields in a frameset document?" not "Why do you think you need a frameset document?"

Comment: I need to access some var values set by Java...

Comment: So this is purely for JavaScript? Write JS into the `<head>` instead of hiding the data in an inappropriate place in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard web page has following layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple html document</title>
    <!-- Headers here -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Body here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

A frameset document has `head` and `frameset` instead of `body`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Headers here -->
  </head>

 <frameset cols="20%, 80%">
   <frameset rows="100, 200">
     <frame src="contents_of_frame1.html">
     <frame src="contents_of_frame2.gif">
   </frameset>
   <frame src="contents_of_frame3.html">
   <noframes>
     <p>This frameset document contains:</p>
     <ul>
       <li><A href="contents_of_frame1.html">Some neat contents</A>
       <li><IMG src="contents_of_frame2.gif" alt="A neat image">
       <li><A href="contents_of_frame3.html">Some other neat contents</A>
     </ul>
   </noframes>
 </frameset>
</html>
```

So if you wish to include some html elements you must include it in one of the frames. Or simply add one additional frame that doesn't take place and incorporate html elements (hidden input fields) there.
On the other side if you wish those html elements in the case that browser doesn't support frameset or they are disabled, then include them in `<noframes>` also.

Answer (score 0):

Frames are SO nineties :) Do you *really* have a valid reason to use them? :) There are LOTS of reasons to avoid them...

Anyway, each frame has its own life, so it depends on which frame does the posting. If you put them in frame X, then you will need to do the posting from that frame, and the others will stay in their state, unaffected.

Comment: Fun fact: Frames are more evil than Haliburton.

Comment: Actually I need to use the hidden form variable on the same page where the <frameset> code is...So wanted to know where should I put it?

Comment: You can't... frameset hosts frames and nothing else. You don't have a body so you can't have code. Check out the IFRAME element, however.

Answer (score 0):

Either use an `<iframe>` to put your document with `<frameset>` inside, or use an `<iframe>` for each of your framed documents.